# Is there any Playwright equivalent for waitForResource in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, casperjs, playwright

Is there any Playwright equivalent for waitForResource in CasperJS? How can I write the below code using Playwright?

```
casper.waitForResource(function test(resource) {
    return resource.url.indexOf("submit") > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `page.waitForRequest()`:

```js
await page.waitForRequest(request => request.url().indexOf('submit') > -1);
```

This will pause the execution until a request is made that contains the string "submit" in its URL.